# store value in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

hi i am new in objective c. i have 3 text field. i have to store that value in one dictionary and dictionary in one array every time when i clicked on button at that time every text field's value will stored in dictionary and dictionary will stored on next index of array.

so can any one help me my code is like given below:

```
[fnamedict setValue:textfield1.text forKey:@"First Name"];

[fnamedict setValue:textfield2.text forKey:@"Last Name"];

[fnamedict setValue:textfield3.text forKey:@"roll number"];

[UserinfoArray addObject:fnamedict];

NSLog(@"%@",UserinfoArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then create the Dictionary assign the values as per keys and then save it in array like

```
[arr adObject:fnamedict];
```

Then you can access that arr according to index.

Make sure allocation should be only one for Array.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, declare array in `.h` and initialize in `.m` file. Here i am assuming and initializing array in `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {  
   UserinfoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
 }
```

than

```
- (IBAction)yourClickEvent:(id)sender {
  NSMutableDictionary *fnamedict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [fnamedict setValue:textfield1.text forKey:@"First Name"];
  [fnamedict setValue:textfield2.text forKey:@"Last Name"];
  [fnamedict setValue:textfield3.text forKey:@"roll number"];

  [UserinfoArray addObject:fnamedict];

  NSLog(@"%@",UserinfoArray);
```